# RadDateTimePicker Value will Change Automaticaly To PersianValue

Tags: c#, telerik

I Use This Code in My Project :

```
DTPicker.Value = DateTime.MinValue;
```

DateTime.MinValue Is: `{01/01/0001 12:00:00 ص}`

But When My Code Is Done, `DtPicker.Value` is: `{22/03/0622 12:00:00 ص}`

How I Can Disable Auto Converting ?

Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you're getting year 1 of the Hijri calendar, which is the equivalent of year 622 in the Gregorian Calendar (Historical reference: The year the prophet Muhammad left Mecca for Medina).

I'm assuming that is the date you're working with, and the one you want, so that the date in the component will be "year 1", which should mean the year of the Hegirae? In other words, your problem is that the component is using the Gregorian calendar, and showing year 622 instead?

I don't know exactly which component you are using (something from Telerik I would assume, since you've included that tag?), but perhaps you can specify language for it?

In WPF, I've done the following in a similar case:

```
MyWpfControl.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Look for some similar option in the API for your component, to override the apparent default / fallback to the Gregorian calendar.